# Foreings Keys en MySQL con otras Base de Datos

Tags: mysql

¿Se puede realizar FK entre campos de diferentes base de datos?

Estoy ocupando el IDE MySQL Workbench y al parecer la IDE no lo permite, pero me gustaría salir de la duda.

Answer (score 0):

Sí, se puede. Podés hacerlo por código directamente..

```
ALTER TABLE Tabla1 
ADD foreign key FK_tabla1(NombreColumnaTabla1)
REFERENCES db2.FromTabla2(NombreColumnaTabla2)
```

Donde `db2` es la otra base de datos.

**Nota:** También es posible agregar que elimine o actualice en cascada, poniendo el código:

```
on delete cascade
on update cascade;
```

Quedaría así:

```
ALTER TABLE Tabla1 
ADD foreign key FK_tabla1(NombreColumnaTabla1)
REFERENCES db2.FromTabla2(NombreColumnaTabla2)
on delete cascade
on update cascade;
```

Comment: No me funciono, estuve intentando la siguiente codigo `ALTER TABLE  "DOCUMENTO" ADD FOREIGN KEY ( "DOC_EMPRESA") REFERENCES "ARMADILLO_BASE"."ENTIDAD" ("ID_ENTIDAD") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;`

Comment: #1005 - Can't create table 'SER_DOCUMENTO_TECNICO.#sql-1cbe_7bfd' (errno: 150)

Comment: tenia que igualar ambos campos, es decir, ambos int(11) y unsigned. Lo resolvi solo @pablo-camus

Comment: Bueno, pero eso era tema de estructura, algo que nunca pusiste en la pregunta. Asumí como obvio que los campos era iguales...por lo que mi respuesta sería correcta teniendo en cuenta la información que nos diste.